# Sequences in Maple [Unable to Execute]

Tags: methods, sequence, maple, simplex

I've been working on a programme to solve any maximisation LPP using the Revised Simplex Method. I have a problem with it though as I'm trying to input a sequence to solve the problem of non-basic variables.
My code is as follows:

```
matmax:=proc(tableau,basic)
local pivot,T,nbv,n,m,b;
T:=evalm(tableau);
n:=coldim(T); m:=rowdim(T);
b:=evalm(basic);
print(evalm(T));
nbv:={seq(i,i=2..n-1)}minus{seq(b[i],i=1..m)};
pivot:=getpiv(T,nbv);
while not pivot=FAIL do
b[pivot[1]]:=pivot[2];
T:=evalm(gauss(col(T,pivot[2]),pivot[1])&*T);
print(evalm(T));
nbv:={seq(i,i=2,..n-1)}minus{seq(b[i],i=1..m)};
pivot:=getpiv(T,nbv);
od;
[evalm(T),evalm(b)];
end;
```

The gauss and getpiv commands are procedures written to work in this programme, these work fine. However upon executing this procedure Maple returns with the message "Error, (in matmax) unable to execute seq" If anyone can give me any help on how to fix this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code. It is very hard to read.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by formatting it, I followed the code block rules when posting the question.

Comment: Indentation.   Also, you need to explain the actual problem is.  You refer to it but you never state exactly what is going wrong.  Are you getting an error?  Are you getting the wrong result?

Comment: The problem is when I try to execute the procedure using matmax(T,Basic) I get maple coming back to me with [Error, (in matmax) unable to execute seq]. I've played around with it since but I keep getting the same error about being unable to execute sequence. Apologies for lack of clarification originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not loaded the `linalg` package before calling your `matxmax` then commands like `coldim` will simplify not work and not produce the integer results for `n` and `m` that are expected when using those in the bound of the `seq` calls. I believe that is why your `seq` error occurs, because `n` and `m` are not being assigned integer intermediate results like you expect.

You could try to remedy this by either loading the package before calling `matmax`, with `with(linalg)`. But that is not so robust, and there are scenarios where it might not work. The `with` command won't work within a procedure body, so you can't put that inside the defn of proc `matmax`.

You could insert a line into `matmax` above, say, the `local` declaration line, like,

```
uses linalg;
```

That would make `coldim` and friends from the `linalg` package work. Unfortunately you've used the name `pivot` as a local variable, and that clashes with the `pivot` export from `linalg` package. So that simple fix via `uses` is not quite enough. You could use some name other than `pivot`, and that simple `uses` line, sure.

My own preference would be to make everything fully explicit, so that later on you or anyone else reading the code can understand it more clearly, even if it's longer. So I would use `linalg[coldim]` instead of `coldim`, and so on for the other exports uses from the `linalg` package within `matmax`.

Having said all the above, you should know that the `linalg` package is deprecated in modern Maple and that `LinearAlgebra` is the new package that offers the functionality you seem to be using. The command names are longer, but using the newer package means that you don't need all those `evalm` calls (or anything like it).

Answer (score -1):

The problem could lie in your gauss and getpiv commands as they may not work with your procedure, could you expand on what they do?

Comment: Answer are not for speculation, you should have made a comment of this instead.